# Play audio on touch down action of button in swiftui

Tags: ios, button, swiftui

I want to play a audio when a button is touched down(as soon as it is clicked) not on touch release in SwiftUI. How can I implement this?

My code looks something like this:

```
struct PressedButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let touchDown: () -> ()
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed ? Color.gray : Color.blue)
            .background(configuration.isPressed ? self.handlePressed() : Color.clear)
    }

    private func handlePressed() -> Color {
        touchDown()
        return Color.clear
    }
}
 

struct DemoPressedButton: View {
    @State var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

    var body: some View {
        Button("Demo") {
            print(">> tap up")
        }
        .buttonStyle(PressedButtonStyle {
            print(">> tap down")
            let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "filename", ofType: "wav")
            self.audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound!)) // receives warning about changing state while updating view
            self.audioPlayer.play() // breaks 
        })
    }
}
```

The code breaks when calling self.audioPlayer.play() .
The custom touchdown code is from this link: [SwiftUI button action as soon as button is clicked not on click release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63316752/swiftui-button-action-as-soon-as-button-is-clicked-not-on-click-release/63316936#63316936)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible approach. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

*Note: you should keep reference to `AVAudioPlayer` while it is playing and better track its state, so this is more appropriate to do in some helper class (like view model)*

```
class PlayViewModel {
    private var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
    func play() {
        let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "filename", ofType: "wav")
        self.audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound!))
        self.audioPlayer.play()
    }
}

struct DemoPressedButton: View {
    let vm = PlayViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Button("Demo") {
            print(">> tap up")
        }
        .buttonStyle(PressedButtonStyle {
            print(">> tap down")
            self.vm.play()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks a bit hacky, `makeBody` of `ButtonStyle` should return static stuff. Actions are expected to take place in `.on...` methods. I would use this solution carefully.